# New version of OpenSSL causes Plone/Zope to not start

Tags: plone, zope

Today's (1 Mar 2016) OpenSSL release has caused the following error when running Plone/Zope
    .buildout/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/persistent/cPersistence.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method

It's hard to see what's going on since it's a binary file. I also tried updating to ZODB3 3.11.0 which yields the following traceback

```
.buildout/eggs/ZConfig-2.9.0-py2.7.egg/ZConfig/loader.py", line 217, in schemaComponentSource
package=package)
ZConfig.SchemaResourceError: could not load package ZServer:
.buildout/eggs/zope.security-3.7.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/security/_proxy.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
  Package name: 'ZServer'
  File name: 'component.xml'
  Package path: None
```

Is there any workaround for this other than reverting OpenSSL?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

`zope security` is a compiled egg, like all the ones ending with `-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg`.
As the traceback says, it cannot find anymore a symbol.
Probably you have to recompile it with the new openssl-dev.

I would try (on a **development** server first):

1. backup your compiled egg (mkdir eggs-backup && mv `eggs/zope.security-3.7.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg eggs-backup/)
2. rerun buildout

This will recompile your missing egg.
Hopefully it works and hopefully it is the only one linked to that library.

Anyway, dependending on the way you patched openssl you may have a lot of other issues (I am thinking about Python, urllib*, curl, wget, ...)

Answer (score 1):

`OpenSSL 1.0.2g` by default doesn't build with SSLv2 (because of the recent *DROWN* attack). You may need to manually build it without `OPENSSL_NO_SSL2` flag.

(but in fact you shouldn't do this if you're doing some server-related stuff, there is a serious security reason because of which it was disabled, see https://drownattack.com)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by upgrading python to 2.7.10+, and then upgrading Pillow and lxml.